# How to transfer contents of one table to another in struts 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2, struts, struts2-jquery

I have two tables displaying two lists. This is my jsp

```
<%@page  contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"language="java"pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s"uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Insert title here</title>

</head>
<body>
<s:form name="tableForm"method="post">
<th>
<s:submit action="verify" key="Add"></s:submit>

</th>
<table id="one">
<thead>
<tr>
<th ></th>
<th> Id</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>RollUp Type</th>
<th>System</th>
</tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
    <s:iterator value="formList1">
        <tr>
        <td><s:checkbox name="checked" fieldValue="%{#attr.ID}" theme="simple" ></s:checkbox>
</td>
<td><s:property value="ID"/></td>
<td><s:property value="NAME"/></td>
<td><s:property value="STATUS"/></td>
<td><s:property value="TYPE"/></td>
<td><s:property value="ROLLUPTYPE"/></td>
<td><s:property value="UNIT"/></td>

        </tr>
        </s:iterator>
     </tbody>
</table>

<table id="two">
<thead>
<tr>
<th ></th>
<th> Id</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>RollUp Type</th>
<th>System</th>
</tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
    <s:iterator value="formList2">
        <tr>
        <td><s:checkbox name="checked" fieldValue="%{#attr.ID}" theme="simple" ></s:checkbox>
</td>
<td><s:property value="ID"/></td>
<td><s:property value="NAME"/></td>
<td><s:property value="STATUS"/></td>
<td><s:property value="TYPE"/></td>
<td><s:property value="ROLLUPTYPE"/></td>
<td><s:property value="UNIT"/></td>

        </tr>
        </s:iterator>
    </tbody>

</table>
<s:a href="#" id="add">add &gt;&gt;</s:a>
    <s:a href="#" id="remove">&lt;&lt; remove</s:a>
</s:form >
</body>
</html>
```

Here I want move the rows that are checked from table 1 to table 2 when I click on add and similarly move the rows that are checked from table 2 to table 1 when I click on remove. I found a similar example on this link http://jsfiddle.net/AkVTw/1/ but it does not work out in my jsp.

It would be very helpful if you can suggest me some sample code for implementing this functionality using **jQuery/javascript.**

I would also like to know is it possible to implement this functionality using **s:optiontransferselect** tag in struts 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with jquery easily. Jquery has "appendTo" function for this type features.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#add').on("click", function(){
      $('#one tbody input:checked').parent().parent().appendTo("#two tbody");
  });

  $('#remove').on("click", function(){
      $('#two tbody input:checked').parent().parent().appendTo("#one tbody");
  });
});
```

I created [Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/3zK7C/). You can test it.

Comment: This works exactly how I wanted but when I put it in the <form></form> it does not work, why is it so?

Comment: @user2077648 Because his code depends on the structure of your table, where mine doesn't. Also my answer was first and his is basically the same as mine. If you try using my answer down below it should solve your problem.

Comment: When you put buttons into the form tags. You must add "return false;" line to end of the button events. Because after click event fire, also form submit is starting. So when you add "return false;", you are canceling form submit event.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to simply clone the rows that are checked and leave them and table 1 while also moving them to table 2 you could use .clone() or if you want to take them away from the first table and move them to the second table you could use appendTo(); 
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eFaca/

```
$("#addRows").click(function(){
$("#table").find("input:checked").closest("tr").appendTo("#table2");
});
$("#removeRows").click(function(){
$("#table2").find("input:checked").closest("tr").appendTo("#table");
});
```